# При запуске программы на SFML\SDL2 появляется ультразвук

Tags: ubuntu, sfml, clion, sdl2

**При создании окна на SFML\SDL2 появляется ультразвук.** Его частота напрямую зависит от размеров окна: если создать окно 200х200, то его вообще не распознать, но если 800х600, слышно очень сильно, работать при таком невозможно.
Проблема совершенно не гуглится, вообще не представляю в чем проблема. Создавал окна на OpenGL, там все в порядке. Раньше, на этом же ноутбуке, программировал SFML на Win11, все было также хорошо. Возможно проблема в самой операционной системе?
Звук, к слову, не из динамиков, тк при подключении наушников звука из них не идет, но ультразвук все еще слышно со стороны ноутбука.
Буду невероятно рад помощи!

---

Ноутбук Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ARH05 | Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64 | Clion C++14

Comment: Если не из звуковой системы, значит свистит железо. Если зависит от размеров окна, значит видяха. Сделайте ревизию на предмет пыли внутри, если не поможет, смотрите в сторону видеодрайверов

Comment: Вероятно просто от большой нагрузки? Может забыли ограничить FPS?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Большое спасибо, я сразу не подумал про FPS, но его ограничение сразу помогло!

Comment: Какие-нибудь дроссели на видеокарте свистят, для некоторых видеокарт это нормально (в обычных играх тоже должно свистеть)